# Add function to context of canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working on creating some libraries for math in javascript, and one of those would be a grapher in canvas. What I'm aiming to do is this.

```
ctx.graph('sin(x)');
```

or something like that. How would I add a method to the ctx of a canvas? One other thing I was considering was something like

```
graph(ctx,'sin(x)');
```

and then using eval to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You extend the prototype of the context object to include your graph.

Put this code in a .js file and include that file with your projects:

```
var canvasPlusGraph=document.createElement("canvas");
var contextPlusGraph=canvasPlusGraph.getContext("2d");

Object.getPrototypeOf(contextPlusGraph).graph=function(...) {

    // do your graph code
}
```